# How to get the id of input field that contains a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a set of input fields that belong to the `mainField` class, like so:

```
<input type="text" class="mainField" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="mainField" id="task">
<input type="text" class="mainField" id="subtask">
```

and in the `JavaScript`,

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();

$(".mainField").change(function () {
   alert(event.target.id);
});
```

While this returns the id when I change normal fields, it doesn't work when I choose a different date in the datepicker. How can I get the id of the field when I pick a different date (without using the datepicker's select method) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `this.id` to get the id of current element.

```
$(".mainField").change(function () {
   alert(this.id);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/995/)

Answer (score 2):

You are using a global event object instead use the event object passed to the handler as the first argument. In IE browser's event model the `event` object was not passed as an argument instead a global variable called `event` was referring to the event object(I think now other browsers also is supporting it). This happens only in the case of native events like the one which is triggered when you change the value of the input field.

But the datepicker's does not trigger the native click event, it is triggered programatically which might not be setting the global event object properly.

```
$(".mainField").change(function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9wg0gu7f/)

This is the same as using `this.id` where `this` refers to the element targeted by the event handler